# Trouble to open XLS file with oledb

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

When I try to open an xls file, I get this error :

```
Rhe Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ''. 
It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.
```

I do several access but I close and dispose the connection all the time. It's on my DEV PC. On the server I get this error : Don't have read/write access on the file. This file is on \networkdisk\directory1\Files

I'll use "ACE.OLEDB" because Jet is not running on x64 server.

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, you need to set "write" permission for this file on development server.

Comment: Of course yes. Set "write" permission for IIS user (Users group).

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a file stream that had not been closed.

Answer (score 0):

in our case, a client uploaded an excel file that is password protected